# How can I turn off creating a sub folder for a new added project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi this question is already asked but its 11 years ago so this problem its solved or anyone have any idea

When I try to add a new project in a solutin folder by browsing a folder, let's say

..\MyFolder

and give a new to my new Project: MyProject

The result seems to be:

..\MyFolder\MyProject\MyProject.cspoj

but I want to achieve

..\MyFolder\MyProject.cspoj

And Icannot see any option or check-box on new project addin dialog box.

How can I turn of the feature to insert the new project in a auto-created subfolder?

Thanks!

Comment: You can get it in ..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj with the IDE by selecting the solution folder.  If it is *really* important to name it MyFolder then you have to rename the directory with Explorer and edit the .sln file by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow my steps to create a new project and then add this new project to the solution. For example, I want to add the project "New" to the solution "Old".
As shown in the figure below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you have suggestions for improving Visual Studio, please visit https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).

Comment: It's not working when you try to add a new project to  solution.
It's creating a whole new project in your screenshot. My Purpose is to add a new project to an already existing solution

Comment: @Yunus    Adding a project in a solution doesn't have this option, but there is a compromise solution that I've been re-edited in the answer.

Comment: this is the hard way but thanks for the help @wenbingent-MSFT